# How do I use a shape's ID from another field to define beginX

Tags: vba, visio, shapesheet, visio-2010

*Background*:  Novice user and VBA programmer - be gentle, please.

*Scenario*: 
Using a Visio (2010) straight line connector;
Currently 1-D Endpoints.BeginX is as follows:

```
=PAR(PNT(Milestone.40!Connections.X1,Milestone.40!Connections.Y1))
```

*What I have*:
A data field in the same shape called BeginItem that contains the Visio ID (e.g. 87) of Milestone.40! above.

*What I need to know*:
If possible, how to change the formula in 1-D Endpoints.BeginX to something like:

```
=PAR(PNT(BeginItemValue!Connections.X1,BeginItemValue!Connections.Y1))
```

and if not possible, is there an alternative way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use code-formatting (begin line with four spaces or put between backquotes)? It's hard to read your question.

Comment: I'll try - gimme a second - sorry!

Comment: Does this help? http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=5806.0

Comment: Can you use `=PAR(PNT(Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(BeginItemValue)!Connections.X1,...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping all.  A combination of all advice led me to an alternative solution.

Instead of trying to refer to the field in the Shapesheet that does contain the BeginItemValue, I built the entire string (in VBA) by concatenating the parts and then updated the BeginX value with it.

```
shpObj.Cells("BeginX").Formula = "=PAR(PNT(" & BeginItemValue & "!Connections.X1," & BeginItemValue & "!Connections.Y1))"
```

That worked well, although I'm sure there are easier ways of doing it.